# SharePoint 2007 - Bind event handler with specific list

Tags: list, sharepoint-2007, event-handling

How to bind event handler with specific list?
In SP 2010 i'm using this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Receivers ListUrl="url_to_my_list">
        ...
    </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

But in SP 2007 ListUrl property not exist!
Help, please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just specify the templateid of the type to which that list instance must be belonging and add code in FeatureActivated event to associate the feature to that particular instance.
If you are not cleared with me, [Go to this article.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/6ca86d4f-5c8c-4e48-8940-811799260e36)